# Google visualization: how to provide user search on a DataTable object?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, jsapi

I have a DataTable object that contains all the data for a Table visualization.

I want to provide a search facility for users of the table, filtering the rows from the Table based on the search query, and then update the visualization with the rows that matched.

DataTable provides the `getFilteredRows` method, but this is not going to be flexible enough (AND conditions for each column simply won't work, for example).

What are my options? All the data already exists client-side, so I should be able to manipulate it using JS code. Is there library functionality that will allow me to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, for now, appears to be no. I came up with this dreadfully-inefficient function as a stop-gap:

```
  function search(query, table) {

      if(query == '') {
          return table;
      }

      var newTable = table.clone();
          newTable.removeRows(0, table.getNumberOfRows());
      var keepRows = [];
      for(i = 0; i < table.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
          for (j = 0; j < table.getNumberOfColumns(); j++) {
                if(table.getValue(i, j).toLowerCase().match(query.toLowerCase())) {
                    keepRows.push(i);
                    break;
                }
        }
      }

      for(r = 0; r < keepRows.length; r++) {
            var row = []
          for(c = 0; c < table.getNumberOfColumns(); c++ ) {
              row.push(table.getValue(keepRows[r], c));
          }

          newTable.addRow(row);
      }

      return newTable;
  }
```